# В Ubuntu 14.04 эмулятор Android говорит Use the '-force-32bit'

Tags: эмулятор, android, ubuntu

Пытаюсь запустить виртуальный девайс. Получаю следующее:

```
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them you will have to do at least one of the following: - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'. - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment. Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release. Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Подскажите, где и как юзать этот `ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT`?

Спасибо!

Comment: Ассоциация:http://askubuntu.com/questions/534044/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated-when-attemping-to-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/534044/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated-when-attemping-to-r

Answer (score 1):

Вы получаете данную ошибку из-за того, что запускаете эмулятор Android на 32-битной версии Linux в то время, как эмулятор показывает лучшую производительность в 64-битной версии Linux.
Использование 32-битного режима считается устаревшим и в будущем (скорее всего), поддержка этого будет удалена и оставлен запуск только на 64-битном Linux.

Для включения возможности запуска в 32-битной среде необходимо запускать эмулятор с ключом `-force-32bit`, или установить переменную окружения `ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT`.
Для создания переменной окружения в своей домашней папке добавьте строку

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

в конец файла `.profile`, например выполнив

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Сохраните файл и перезагрузите машину, чтобы изменения вступили в силу.

Answer (score 0):

B Eclipse
Menu -> Run -> Run configurations

выбрать закладку Target

в самом низу в поле 'Additional emulator command options' вставить значение

-force-32bit

Фсе